# Getting the listview item

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` that I fill its items by downloading a user tweets and I'm trying to get the item (the tweet) to a toast on an `onClick`, but I'm getting weird data not the text.

```
 public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        i = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewTweets);

        new LongOperation().execute("");

        i.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {

             // ListView Clicked item index
             itemPosition = position;

             // ListView Clicked item value
             itemValue =  adapter.getItem(position).toString();

              // Show Alert 
              Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , 1000)
                .show();

            }

       }); 

        return rootView;
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

            String[] srch = new String[] {name};
            ResponseList<User> users = null;
                statusListTextOnly = new ArrayList<String>();
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (User user : users) {
              System.out.println("Friend's Name " + user.getName()); // this print my friends name
                  if (user.getStatus() != null) 
                  {
                  System.out.println("Friend timeline");
                  try {
                    statusess = twitter.getUserTimeline(name);
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
            }  


                return null;
        }        

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
            List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

            Tweet[] stockArr = new Tweet[tweets.size()];

            adapter = new TweetAdapter(FragmentTab1.this.getActivity(),
                    R.layout.listview_item_row, stockArr);

            i.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {  
          }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

currently: the toast is `Position: 18 Listitem: xx.xxx.xxx.xx@416f985`

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx `is my package name`
```

Comment: try String  itemValue = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

Comment: obviously your Item, whatever class it is, doesnt have a human readable toString method, implement one and you should be fine

Comment: Can you paste the code of the ListAdapter?

Comment: @PadmaKumar still same toast

Comment: @DanielBo show me how to please

Comment: @AdityaKamath okay I will

Comment: Avtar Guleria did explain it, check his answer

Comment: In your Tweet Class override toString() method to get the desired output...Paste your Tweet class so that we can help you out :)..As you have not implemented toString() method the default toString implementaion that is the memory address is being printed.

Comment: I have inserted my whole class

Comment: We need to see your Adapter code to help out. Overriding toString() is one possibility, but there might be a more elegant way to do this. On a unrelated note, you shouldn't get the item directly from the adapter, if your ListView has header views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting such weird Toast is because the text containing the Toast is an object of type Tweet.

What you need to do is get the text from that object. I don't know how your Tweet class looks, but I think it would be something like this:

```
itemValue =  adapter.getItem(position).title;
```

This way the Toast will display a string and not an object.

Comment: thank you Kevin sorry didn't accept it cuz someone else gave me the answer first

Comment: I answered earlier, it was 16 hours ago and he answered 15 hours ago. I changed my answer because I did .getTitle() and than saw in your code that it was just .title. But it doesn't matter. Thanks for the +1!

Comment: Oh, sorry man. I have accepted your answer, because I thought that I saw that .title from him earlier than yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement toString() method in your object of 'i' Type.

for e.g 
if i is a object of Student Class like:

```
Class Student{
String name;
int marks;


public String toString(){
return ("Name="+name +"Marks="+marks);
}
```

As shown above you have to implement toSTring method. If you do not implement toString method in java/android default toString will return class name with @some address like currently it is returning.

Comment: But I don't know how to connect that idea with my class

Comment: The problem is with this line: String  itemValue = (String) i.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();   Here, i is the Object of The class in which you have to override the toString() method. Let say if i is the object of Student class then you have to override toString() method in Student Class.

Comment: Okay but still I don't know how to use that with my code, if I just use that code toString() it will automatically work? *I dont have my pc atm to try*

Answer (score 1):

`onItemClick` is giving `position` variable which you can use to retrieve the list item in that position.

Comment: From your tweets array.

Comment: A code or more brief explaining would help, cuz I'm not understanding u well.

Answer (score 1):

The answers before explained why you are getting a "**weird toast**" so to fix that, in your `tweetAdapter` class you are using `tweet.title` as a `string`.

So try this:

```
        adapter.getItem(position).title;
```

Because the `adapter` will get the item that is sent through your `TweetAdapter`, using the `tweet.title` here will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String  itemValue = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: without his code, you cant be sure that the item he gets actually is a textview, which might lead to classcastexceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your Adapter from setOnItemClickListener using

```
TweetAdapter mAdapter=((TweetAdapter)parent.getAdapter());
```

So on `mAdapter.getItem(position)` will help.

Comment: I get ** Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? to TweetAdapter ** error from parent.getAdapter();

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your Tweet[] stockArr array globally and can access it inside listview's onItemClick listener as -:

stockArr(position).getTweet().toString();

Anything you can access from Tweet object from above solution.

Comment: that doesn't work too, I get **The method stockArr(int) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}** from stockArr